# Calculate integral of exponential to the x suared (Simple Gaussian Integral)

Tags: integration, exponential-function, polar-coordinates, gaussian-integral

For: $\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}}dx $

A method I saw (but did not get the right result) was to set:

$I = \int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}}dx $

and

$I = \int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-y^{2}}{2}}}dx $

then by calculating  $I^2 $ I could make use of polar coordinates since $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $dxdy=rdxd\theta$

Any other process I may use instead? I just need to be pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polar coordinates are useful only to calculate the integral: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}}dx $$ You cannot calculate the integral $I$ exactly,  because the primitive of the gaussian can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions. You can read here:[The easiest way to evaluate Gaussian integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142070/the-easiest-way-to-evaluate-gaussian-integral)